# Problem building libsvm-3.0 on CentOs 5.5 for Python-2.7.1

Tags: python, centos, libsvm

trying to install libsvm-3.0 for an alternative python build (python-2.7.1 instead of default 2.4) on CentOs 5.5.  This python is installed in /opt/python2.7.  I downloaded the source files and ran MAKE in the main dir and the python subdir.  Then I copied everything to /opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libsvm

When I did this on Macintosh 10.6.6, I had to do a couple of extra steps that were not in the instructions.  They are described on my blog [here](http://codexpython.blogspot.com).  The key step was adding the following to svm.py

```
 import os.path
_PATH = os.path.join( *os.path.split(__file__)[:-1] )
```

and modifying this first statement

```
if find_library('svm'):
   libsvm = CDLL(find_library('svm'))
elif find_library('libsvm'):
   libsvm = CDLL(find_library('libsvm'))
else:
   if sys.platform == 'win32':
      libsvm = CDLL('../windows/libsvm.dll')
   else:
      libsvm = CDLL('../libsvm.so.2')
```

to look like this:

```
if find_library('svm'):
  libsvm = CDLL(find_library('svm'))
elif find_library('libsvm'):
  libsvm = CDLL(find_library('libsvm'))
else:
  if sys.platform == 'win32':
    libsvm = CDLL(os.path.join(_PATH,'windows','libsvm.dll'))
  else:
    libsvm = CDLL(os.path.join(_PATH,'libsvm.so.2'))
```

However, neither of these configurations are working on this Linux version.  I am definitely not a Linux person, so I have no clue what could be wrong.

Working in the interpreter to try to figure this out, I noticed that cytpes.util.find_library('svm') or ctypes.util.find_library("libsvm.so.2") return empty values, so it definitely does not know where the .so is.

I was able to manually force the location in the interpreter by setting libsvm= CDLL(os.path.abspath("libsvm.so.2")).  Then I could import svm during that session only.

Any help is much appreciated.

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, problem solved.  Stupid me. Instead of adding `__init__.py`
 to the libsvm dir, I added init.py. Once I changed that, it works.  Still, the need to add `__init__.py` should be included in the libsvm-3.0 installation notes IMHO.